# Naming Slide Images on Export in PowerPoint 2007

Tags: c#, vba, powerpoint

`Presentation.Export(filename, "PNG", sizeX, sizeY`); creates thumbnail images of all slides in the PowerPoint presentation.

My problem is that the thumbnail filenames change according to the Language of PowerPoint.
On an English PowerPoint, the thumbnail files are: "slide1.png", "slide2.png", etc.
On Hebrew PowerPoint: שקופית1.png,  שקופית2.png, etc.

How can I control the name of each slide on export to PNG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to control the name of the exported slides, use the [Slide.Export](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb251164.aspx) method instead with a loop.

Answer (score -2):

You may set the slides to use the original PPT file name and path, and to have a numbering set after the PPT file name by using the below Visual Basic macro.

**Note:**
You may INCREASE the exported PNG resolution prior to doing so, via the REGEDIT.

```
Sub SaveSlidesAsPNG()
    Dim PowerPointApp As Object
    Dim PowerPointPres As Object
    Dim Slide As Object
    Dim SlideCount As Integer
    Dim SavePath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim SlideIndex As Integer
    
    ' Set the PowerPoint application object
    Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    
    ' Open the active presentation
    Set PowerPointPres = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation
    
    ' Get the number of slides in the presentation
    SlideCount = PowerPointPres.Slides.Count
    
    ' Get the current file path and remove the filename
    SavePath = Left(PowerPointPres.FullName, InStrRev(PowerPointPres.FullName, "\"))
    
    ' Loop through each slide
    For SlideIndex = 1 To SlideCount
        Set Slide = PowerPointPres.Slides(SlideIndex)
        
        ' Create the filename for the PNG file
        FileName = SavePath & "\" & Left(PowerPointPres.Name, InStrRev(PowerPointPres.Name, ".") - 1) & "-" & SlideIndex & ".png"
        
        ' Save the slide as a PNG file
        Slide.Export FileName, "PNG"
    Next SlideIndex
    
    ' Close the presentation and quit PowerPoint
    PowerPointPres.Close
    PowerPointApp.Quit
    
    ' Clean up the objects
    Set Slide = Nothing
    Set PowerPointPres = Nothing
    Set PowerPointApp = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "Slides saved as PNG files!"
End Sub
```

Comment: No need to modify the registry. Slide.Export also takes optional height and width parameters (in pixels) that let you set the size you want/need.